# How can I run some code only after all callbacks complete on a jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some animation code with a callback.  I need a piece of code to run only after that callback has completed.  I do not want to modify the animation code or callback.  How can I make sure all callbacks have run before running some additional code.  Should I be looking at the queue? When an animation completes but there are still callbacks pending, is that item removed from the queue?  What should I be doing here?

```
var animateFunc = function () {
        $('#search').animate({ height: '0px', opacity: '0.0' }, 'fast', 'linear',                          function () {
            $('#search-state').val(searchContainerState.currentPage);

        });
    };
```

example call:

```
animateFunc();
someOtherFunc(); //someOtherFunc needs to run after the animation callback code.
```

How do I do this correctly?
Thanks!!

Comment: *I do not want to modify the animation code or callback*... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$( '#search' ).queue( someOtherFunc );
```

This will add that function to the end of the effects queue, which means that it will be invoked after the existing animation operations.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BkmWg/

Answer (score 0):

Let `animateFunc`  take a callback as argument and then wherever you use `animateFunc` if you want anything to execute on animation complete pass the handler as an argument to it. Try this.

```
var animateFunc = function (callback) {
        $('#search').animate({ height: '0px', opacity: '0.0' }, 
            'fast', 'linear', function () {
                $('#search-state').val(searchContainerState.currentPage);

                if($.isFunction(callback)){
                    callback();
                }
        });
    };

animateFunc(someOtherFunc);
```

I know I am modifying the `animateFunc` callback which is not required by you, but this is the right way to ensure the animation is complete and you want to execute any callback.